# How to link the title attribute of an image to a pop-up div

Tags: javascript, html, title

I am building a website to show my jewelry pieces. I have images without descriptions that are visible for the user because of my page layout.

While I was looking at a colleague's website I noticed something I might use http://www.sarahschuchard.com/sites/objects.html. Here is a carousel JS that links the alt and title attribute of an image to a mouseover function which shows these attributes in a div.

I tried to isolate this particular code but my knowledge of JS is very limited so it didn't work out for me. Can someone help me with implementing this idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I came up with an answer that suits my needs.
Indeed I started to consider using a custom tooltip to show additional information instead of the carousel thingy.

My tooltip of choice was Tiptip. It was easy to implement in itself, but it started to interfere with the lightbox2 plugin I installed. It still showed the default tooltip(next to the custom one) when hovering over image links with TITLE attributes.

The default tooltip started to use the TITLE attribute of the A tag instead of the nested IMG tag. The option of leaving out the TITLE was not desirable because lightbox uses this attribute to show information.

Blocking out the TITLE with a mouseover JS code would give the same effect as deleting the TITLE attribute.

After some tinkering and looking around i developed a way around this problem.

I read about the option of making lightbox use an other attribute then the TITLE one of the A tag. The corresponding code was easy to locate in the JS file. (around lines 166 and 174 for lightbox 2, I don't know for other lightbox like plugins). I changed it to the ALT attribute(SEO purposes) but I recon you can change it to a custom one to suit your needs.

this paved a way to insert the following JS code in the HEAD tag to bann the default tooltip from the page in a way search engines can still see your attributes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').mouseover(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title', $this.attr('title'));
        // Using null here wouldn't work in IE, but empty string will work just fine.
        $this.attr('title', '');
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.data('title'));
    });
});
```

Here is the result http://www.coenhofhuizen.com/Sites/sieraden.html

Custom tooltip compatible with lightbox.

Hope it helps other people

Answer (score 1):

This is called a custom tooltip. What you want to do is create a container and show it on `mouseover` and then remove it on `mouseout`.

E.g.

```
$('image').mouseover(function (event) {
    $('<div></div>').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': event.pageX + 10,
        'top': event.pageY + 10,
        'z-index': 100
    }).addClass('tooltip').text($(this).attr('title')).appendTo(document);
}).mouseout(function (event) {
    $('.tooltip').remove();
});
```

Comment: if his js isnt good, i dont think he can do jQuery..

Comment: @I-love-php this code is fully functional, so even if the user doesn't know javascript he can copy/paste the code with the only exception that the image selector needs to be made as specific as the need requires.

Comment: agreed...guess if he has a prob hell comment

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try to implement it now and see what it does.

Comment: Although this is also an option this is not what I meant.
I do not feel the need to change the style of the tooltip, I would like to have the same effect as the carousel JS in the example has when hovering over an image. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is using Lightbox in the website. 
You can download it freely here:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
In principle it's easy to install (check the examples) and it uses the title tag of your image as a caption for the popup box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
i have already used this code. But what I would like is before you click you see a short description e.g. the title attribute shown in a pre placed div.